# Change default Path on Telerik Upload component

Tags: file-upload, path, telerik, telerik-mvc

**The Objective:**

Set a different path by default on my Telerik Upload component.

**The Problem:**

The path should be like "\\Server\Folder" and the porperty ScriptFilePath requires a path starting with ~/. I was looking telerik tutorials but ther's no help about that.

**The Code:** View
C# MVC3

```
               @(Html.Telerik().Upload()

                               .Name("attach")
                               .Multiple(false)
                               **.ScriptFilesPath("~/")**                               
                               .Async(async => async
                                                   .Save(Actions.FileLoader_GetFile, Controllers.FileLoader)
                                                   .Remove(Actions.FileLoader_Remove, Controllers.FileLoader)
                                                   .AutoUpload(true)

                               ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with Teklerik, it is not posible.

> Is not possible to set a "default' directory for the `<input type='file' />` html element, this is restriction by the browsers and there is no way to workaround it.

I suppose that this restriction makes sense since there is no guarantee that the folder set as default for the upload will exist on the given client.